# CSS/HTML - Make fixed div take 20% of screen and the other be scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a layout that has a fixed DIV on the bottom of the screen the other DIV and its the content should be scrollable.

I want the first DIV to be dynamic, meaning that the children items displayed inside can grow in height and they should be visible in 80% of height of the screen.

the other DIV should be fixed and always be 20% of the height on the screen (window).

The fixed DIV is pretty straightforward to be implemented with `position:fixed` but the mainContent DIV is getting overlapped by the bottom DIV. So for that I added `padding-bottom` to the body.

What I'm trying to achieve is that min-height/height of the upper (mainContent) div should always be till the top of the bottom DIV.

I added my code here http://jsfiddle.net/hp2b64ot/3/.

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/ you need to implement this

Comment: Add your `padding-bottom: 20%` to the div you are scrolling and make sure you set the body to `margin: 0; padding: 0;`. Make sure `html, body` has a `height:100%`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explanation http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties

> **The percentage is calculated with respect to the width** of the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and
>   'padding-bottom'. If the containing block's width depends on this
>   element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

So your padding 20% of *body* element depends on body width.

Use helper element to solve this problem, for example

```
<div class="col-md-12 bannerEdge-fix"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hp2b64ot/13/

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your support, you can us vh units, which means:

```
body {padding-bottom: 20vh;}

.fixed {height: 20vh}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hp2b64ot/12/

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very helpful, though comment by Seldon 100% resolved the issue.